# CakePHP Plugin CSS

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I create a plugin for application installation in CakePHP. In my plugin folder I have create the folder structure:

```
/app
    /Plugin
        /Install
            /Controller
                /Component
            /Model
                /Behavior
            /View
                /Helper
                /Install
                /Layouts
                    /Installer.ctp
            /webroot
                /css
                    default.css
```

Now in my **Installer.ctp** I have enter that code:

```
<?php

    echo $this->Html->css('/Install/default.css');

?>
```

but the CakePHP return to me the URL **/cp/Install/default.css**

Any idea on how to make the plugin to load the correct file from within the plugin folder **webroot** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it should be

```
echo $this->Html->css('/install/css/default');
```

also note the lowercase i

Comment: js would be $this->Html->script('/install/js/default');

Comment: I can't get this to work - going to http://mysite.com/plugin_name/css/default.css gives a "PluginName.CssController not found" error.  Can you help?

Comment: did you read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html#required-steps-to-upgrade - and do you have the AssetDispatcher in your filter `Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters')`?

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old post, but I'd like to share another approach: you can pass 'PluginName.css-file' as parameter:

```
echo $this->Html->css('Install.default');
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: I like this approach, I think this is better, thanks

Comment: Throws me a *Missing Controller* error, the files are there though.